# Spacebar blocked in InlineEditBox with TextArea editor

Tags: dojo, inlineeditbox

I have a customized DOJO widget and template rendering an InlineEditBox(dijit.form) with dijit.form.Textarea.
InlineEditBox itself is wrapped under ContentPane of a TabController (dijit.layout).

Most things work=> TabContainer is rendered, ContentPanes are rendered.

InlineEditBox too, seems to be rendered with default hand writing symbol (noValueIndicator). When I click, I get a TextArea where I can enter all characters, but SPACEBAR(atleast among the common characters that I have tried). Seems, some keypress eventhandler blocking the SPACEBAR key press. Notably, TextBox hierarchy widgets (as editor widgets in InlineEditBox) seems to be responding to SPACEBAR, but html textarea rendering widgets (tried TextArea, SimpleTextArea) simply ignore SPACEBAR. Wonder, who is blocking the SPACEBAR.

Unable to see anything on the net related to the issue. Would appreciate any help.

Code Snippet:

```
<div class="tab_container" dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" doLayout="false" controllerWidget="dijit.layout.TabController">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="tab_one" title="ONE"></div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="tab_two" title="TWO"></div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="tab_three" title="THREE">
        <div dojoType="dijit.InlineEditBox" class="inline_edit_box" editor="dijit.form.Textarea"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an internal issue.

There was a Space key-press blocker in another section of code.

Thanks!